# scaffold-mobile-app scripts out command error wile Upgrading Azure mobile services to Mobile app services

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

I am just trying to upgrade my Azure Mobile Service(AMS) to Mobile app service with the help of documentation link provided [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-upgrading-from-mobile-services/#comments).

I have successfully migrated my Mobile service with the help of button provided on portal. After that I also installed node server on my local machine and installed following node package -

**npm i -g azure-mobile-apps-compatibility**

I have also obtained my Azure Mobile Service script files. Following is my folder hierarchy of Scripts folder -

[image]

Now here in this step I am stuck. I am trying to Scaffold the new Azure Mobile Apps backend with the help of following Node command -

**scaffold-mobile-app scripts out**

When I executed above command, I am getting following errors in node command prompt -

[image]

After looking at the errors I thought that there is some problem with my municipality api files. So I also tried removing my municipality.js and permissions.js file. After that I re executed the scaffolding command. But it again gave me the following error -

[image]

I did some research to resolve this error. But I did not get any relevant help in that context. Can someone help/ guide me so that I can proceed further in this upgrade activity?

Comment: This is a bug in the compatibility package that doesn't deal with child directories in the shared folder. We will release a fix for this soon and respond here.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response Dale. Waiting for the new update :).

Comment: Updated package (0.0.7) on npm now. npm i -g azure-mobile-apps-compatibility to upgrade. Give it a test and let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks Dale for this quick fix. I will try it and let you know further

Comment: Hi Dale, Its working now :). Thanks a lot for the fix.